# How can I get distinct documents on a field with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, distinct, coffeescript, mongoose

My code is:

```
Checkin.distinct field, conditions, (err, checkinResults) ->
  doStuff()
```

However, `checkinResults` is simply a series of `ObjectId`'s. I need the full document. Any ideas?

Comment: It is. Sorry, I should have been clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct` method only returns the selected field, not the whole documents, so you need two (or more) queries:

```
getCheckinsByX = (field, cb) ->
    Checkin.find({ field }).limit(x).exec (err, checkins) ->
        cb err, { field, checkins }

Checkin.distinct field, conditions, (err, results) ->
    async.map results, getCheckinsByX, (err, checkinsByField) ->
        # use list of checkins
```

This could generate a lot of db queries, so you might want to look into the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/), or a way of making a single `Checkin` query + grouping on the client.

Comment: It won't work in this context. The distinct call is not returning a list of Checkin models - it returns a list of field properties and reftype is lost.

Comment: @Greg I've updated the answer to remove the incorrect suggestion.